# Change event not triggered on ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In the below code I have a dropdown `(id-name)` which populated from `listplace.php'. Also made another ajax call which when the dropdown item is selected it lists the specific product from`dataprod.php`

Problem: when I click on the specific item from drop-down it does not trigger the Ajax event

I checked the `dataprod.php` it works correctly, but even after binding the change event with my dropdown box I m not getting the result. Please help..

```
<select id="name">
  <option selected disabled>Please select</option>
</select>

<?php if (isset($_GET['place']) && $_GET['place'] != '') { ?>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {place: '<?= $_GET["place"] ?>'},
            url: 'listplace.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
                if (json.option.length) {
                    var $el = $("#name"); 
                    $el.empty(); // remove old options
                    for (var i = 0; i < json.option.length; i++) {
                        $el.append($('<option>',
                            {
                                value: json.option[i],
                                text: json.option[i]
                            }));
                    }
                }else {
                    alert('No data found!');
                }
            }
        });
    </script>

<script>
$(document.body).on('change',"#name",function (e) {
   //doStuff
  var name1 = this.value;
 $.ajax ({
     data: {name1: '<?= $_GET["name1"] ?>'},
     url: 'dataprod.php',
     success: function (response) {
         console.log(response);

    $('.products-wrp').html('');
    $('.products-wrp').hide();
    $('.products-wrp').html(response);
    $('.products-wrp').show();            
        },

    });
</script>     
<?php } ?>
```

dataprod.php

```
<?php
include("config.inc.php");
$name1 = $_POST['name1'];
$results = $mysqli_conn->query("SELECT product_name, product_desc, product_code,  
product_image, product_price FROM products_list where product_name='$name1'");

$products_list =  '<ul id ="products_list" class="products-wrp">';
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
$products_list .= <<<EOT
<li>
<form class="form-item">
<h4>{$row["product_name"]}</h4>
<div>
<img src="images/{$row["product_image"]}" height="62" width="62">
</div>
<div>Price : {$currency} {$row["product_price"]}<div>
</form>
</li>
EOT;
}
$products_list .= '</ul></div>';
echo $products_list;
?>
```

Comment: did you give the alert in onchange jquery?alert is triggering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the selected value in the ajax call.

change this line from

```
var name1 = this.value;
 $.ajax ({
     data: {name1: '<?= $_GET["name1"] ?>'},
```

to

```
 var name1 = this.value;
 $.ajax ({
     data: {name1: name1},
     type: 'POST',
```

Comment: I changed it but still not getting the result.

Comment: when the ajax call is called what is echo $products_list; showing ?

Comment: if its showing blank after the ajax call then you might have to check your sql $results debug it and see if the values are coming properly

Comment: can you echo the result $name1 after this line $name1 = $_POST['name1'];

Comment: karthick I echo $name1 , but not displaying .. hope the problem is with my $name1

Comment: please add type: 'POST' in your ajax call. Totally missed it. The default call is GET if you don't specify it

Comment: karthick thanks tried it.. ur changes were significant to my code, but my result is not visible maybe some other issues

Answer (score 0):

HTML:
you can store the values in hidden field like:

```
<input type='hidden' name='name1' id='name1' value='<?= $_GET["name1"] ?>'>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document.body).on('change',"#name",function (e) {
   //doStuff
  var name1 = $('#name1').val();
 $.ajax ({
     data: {name1: '<?= $_GET["name1"] ?>'},
     url: 'dataprod.php',
     success: function (response) {
         console.log(response);

    $('.products-wrp').html('');
    $('.products-wrp').hide();
    $('.products-wrp').html(response);
    $('.products-wrp').show();            
        },

    });
```